# V 3.4 Annotate Geometry Nodes

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

Is there a way to add text or annotation frames in the geo nodes editor? (to, for example, document methods or problems for oneself or for future users). I want these to appear in the editor, not on the layout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following description applies to both the Geometry and Material nodes editors and was discovered after experimenting so I may have missed some options.
Select your required nodes and frame them with <kbd>Ctrl-J</kbd>. Unchecking <kbd>Shrink</kbd> on the Properties section of the N-panel will allow you to manually resize the frame by dragging the edges and to move the nodes around in the frame to make room for the annotation. The <kbd>Label Size</kbd> applies to both the top frame label and the annotation.
[image]

Open a Text workspace, add and name a new document, then enter your required annotation text.

[image]

In the node workspace, click <kbd>Text</kbd> in the side panel and select your text document name. This will then be added to the frame.
[image]

You can change the text in the editor and this will be updated on the frame when you click anywhere in the node workspace.

Comment: Re-reading the question again, you can also press 'W' to bring up the toolbar and use the annotation tools, but you'd have to write any text with the mouse or a pen and graphics tablet rather than typing.

Comment: Thanks everyone. These tips are incredibly valuable to me and I couldn't find it on the exchange, nor in the manual. Hope it helps others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Left Click Select , CTRL+J, Left Click Frame, F2

Comment: You can also add the contents of a text file to the frame background from the Properties > Text section on the N panel, but you then have to resize the frame and move the nodes around so that they don't cover it which is a bit of a fiddle.

Comment: @JohnEason ... this deserves stand-alone answer with a single screen that is awesome I didn't notice it :)

Comment: @vklidu I'll add an answer shortly. I'd only realised that it was possible myself after I saw this question and had a play! You can actually create the annotation in the Text editor and use that in the frame!

Comment: @JohnEason For resizing the frame that the nodes don't cover the text it might also be useful to know that you can disable the _Shrink_ option in the _Properties_ which is enabled by default and mostly ignored by most people, so you should add this in your answer :)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Yes I saw that when experimenting last night and was going to add that as part of my answer otherwise the nodes just cover the annotation text.